# Is $\sqrt{f(x)}$ convex if $f(x)$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume $f(x)\geq 0$. Is $\sqrt{f(x)}$ convex if $f$ is convex?? I was guessing it to be indeed.

Comment: Hint: try something simple, maybe $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: That seems convex to me if it's absolute function.

Comment: $|x|$ *is* convex (and non-negative as well). How about $\sqrt{|x|}$ though?

Comment: convex as well.

Comment: Maybe not. Look twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and twice differentiable. Note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{f(x)} &= \frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}} \\
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sqrt{f(x)} &= \frac{2\sqrt{f(x)}f''(x)-(f'(x))^2/\sqrt{f(x)}}{4f(x)}
\end{align}$$
For the second derivative to be nonnegative, we need the numerator to be nonnegative in addition to $f(x)>0$:
$$\begin{align}
2\sqrt{f(x)}f''(x)&\geq(f'(x))^2/\sqrt{f(x)} \\
f''(x)&\geq\frac{1}{2}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}
\end{align}$$
This is obviously a stronger condition than $f''(x) \geq 0$. It requires the function to be curved stronger than what convexity requires. Functions like $x^2$ and $\exp(x)$ satisfy this criterion, while $|x|$ does not.

Comment: That's a nice way to do it with the second-derivative test.